# Switching int and string arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working on this assignment for some time and I'm stuck. The purpose is to make an int array with numbers 1-5, and then make a string array with 6-10, then put the 6-10 in the int array and the 1-5 in the string array, and afterwards do some stuff to it. I've done most of the "stuff" to it ( multiply, add etc ) but I can't figure out how to switch the two arrays with each other. I've tried a few methods that I found on stackoverflow but I couldn't implement them. Currently the methods I tried are commented out

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Rebel
{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {  
      int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
      String[] words = {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

      System.out.println(numbers.getClass().getName()); // test data type before converting
      System.out.println(words.getClass().getName()); // test data type before converting

      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) // prints out int array
      {
         System.out.println(numbers[i]);
      }

      for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) // prints out string array
      {
         System.out.println(words[j]);
      }
      /* Switching the arrays 


      //java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers[]); // converts int to string
      // numbers = Arrays.asList(words).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); // convert string to int

     // int [] tempNum = Arrays.asList(words.split(",")).stream().map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

     //int [] tempNum = Arrays.asList(words.split(",")).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
     */ 

      System.out.println("There are " + numbers.length + " elements in numbers array");
      System.out.println("There are " + words.length + " elements in words array");
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers));
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(words));

      for(int num: numbers)
      {
         num = num*4;
         System.out.println(num);
      }
      for (String word: words)
      {
         System.out.println(stringMultiply(word, 3)); // s = word, and n = 3;
      }
      System.out.println(numbers.getClass().getName()); // test data type after converting
      System.out.println(words.getClass().getName()); // test data type after converting


   }


   public static String stringMultiply(String s, int n) /// "multiply" string
   {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Before try out the `streams` and 'mappers` it is better to try out the basic Java stuff for implement the required functionality. Swapping two variables will be a good starting point to read more and complete the assignment. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with:

```
numbers = Arrays.asList(words).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

But you need to save the `numbers` array first, so you can use it later to create the `words` array.

```
int[] temp = numbers;
numbers = Stream.of(words).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
words = IntStream.of(temp).boxed().map(Object::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
//      The data
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String[] words = {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

    //      Create a new tempNumber array with word length
            int[] tempNumber = new int[words.length];

    //      Set i=0 just for a shorter for loop
            int i = 0;
    //      Enter each string to the tempNumber array.
            for( String s : words )
            {
                tempNumber[i++] = Integer.valueOf(s);
            }

    //      Set i to - so it can be reused.
            i = 0;

    //      Create a new tempNumber array with number length
            String[] tempString = new String[numbers.length];
    //      Enter each int to the tempNumber array
            for( int n : numbers )
            {
                tempString[i++] = String.valueOf(n);
            }

    //      Set numbers array to the one we created.
            numbers = tempNumber;
    //      Set string Array to the one we created;
            words = tempString;

    //      Output the result
            System.out.println("The numbers array has: "+Arrays.toString(numbers));
            System.out.println("The string array has: "+Arrays.toString(words));

    //      Output~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //      The numbers array has: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    //      The string array has: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
```

Comment: I tried implementing this. The problem I got was that both arrays became ints. Which is not allowed. 1-5 is suppose to become strings and 6-10 is suppose to become ints. Other than that it works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are probably easier ways, but I did it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
    String[] words = {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    int[] mixed = new int[numbers.length + words.length];

    //loop through all numbers in the numbers[] array and put them in mixed
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length;)
    {
        mixed[i] = numbers[i];
        i++;

        //if i reached the length of the numbers[] array, do the following:
        if (i >= numbers.length)
        {
            //continue using the i variable as index indicator while adding converting the string values into integers and adding them to the mixed[] array
            for (int b = 0; b < numbers.length; b++)
            {
                mixed[i] = Integer.valueOf(words[b]);
                i++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //print array
    for (int x : mixed)
    {
        System.out.print(x + " | ");
    }
}
}
```